# timestamp conversion for below query

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I have these data '2019-12-19T01:39:29.6941632Z' as varchar2 datatype

i have to replace the T and Z and also to convert the datatype to timestamp

I tried this query but won't work

```
to_timestamp(replace(replace('2019-12-19T01:39:29.6941632Z','T',''),'Z'),'YYYY.MM.DD:HH24:MI:SS')
```

Please help me

Answer (score 2):

My proposal would be this one:

```
CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2019-12-19T01:39:29.6941632Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T":HH24:MI:SS.FFTZR') AS TIMESTAMP)
```

Comment: The `'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF9TZH:TZM'` format mask will also work for Zulu time.

Answer (score 1):

As a slight variation on @Wernfried's conversion, since you aren't using the time zone information you can treat the fixed Z as a character literal too, like the fixed T. Then you can use `to_timestamp()`, and don't need to `cast()`:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-12-19T01:39:29.6941632Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"')
```

The `YYYY`, `MM`, `DD`, `HH24`, `MI`, `SS` and `FF` parts of the format mask are as described [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-22F2B830-261E-4BF0-91FB-6A1DAFC6D0A3). The `"T"` and `"Z"` are [character literals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A) so the function knows not to try to interpret them as part of the timestamp value; which means you don't need to remove/replace them. And the overall format mask matches the source string - by default Oracle is forgiving of using the wrong separators (like `.` instead of `-`) but it's better to use the correct expected values anyway.

e.g.:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP('2019-12-19T01:39:29.6941632Z', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF"Z"')
FROM DUAL;

19-DEC-19 01.39.29.694163200 AM
```

(and you can then handle or format the timestamp however you want)

Comment: Thanks Alex ... it helped
and one help

Comment: can u explain the concept in one line..it ll be really helpful for me as a SQL beginner

Comment: @BarathTM - I included a link to the documentation on character literals in format masks, i.e. the `"T"` and `"Z"` parts. The `to_timestamp()` essentially ignores those characters in the source string, so you don't need to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the `replace()`.  And use the correct format.

This works:

```
select to_timestamp(replace(replace('2019-12-19T01:39:29.6941632Z', 'T', ''), 'Z', ''), 'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SS.FF')
from dual
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2a8d051f49d3484a2872d363f6c5f9f6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: still getting this error msg ''date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Comment: @BarathTM . . . I included a db<>fiddle showing that it works.